# JSTree, traverse and edit each nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, edit, jstree, traversal

I'm new to JSTree, but really want to know how do you traverse jstree to edit each node? 
I wrote a recursive function to traverse each nodes, but strange thing to me is,

1. I take out the data using var treeData =
   $('tree').get_json(true);
2. I put this data into the function , traverse(treeData);

   traverse(treeData){ //do some editing work here.
   traverse(treeData'schildren); 
   }

Wired, after the traverse finished, nothing is changed. 
I've already set the 'check_callback' to true.

Anyone can help？
BEST regards 
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `get_json` you only get json object. To change nodes you have to access them. Also you have to use `redraw` function to update nodes based on changed data.

An example of your functionality could look like:

```
function traverse(node) {
    node.text += ' too';
    for (var i=0, len = node.children.length; i<len; i++) {
        var childNode = $("#tree").jstree().get_node(node.children[i]);
        traverse(childNode);
    }         
}

var treeData = data.node;
traverse(data.node); 
$('#tree').jstree().redraw(true);
```

Check fiddle - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/sjd6fnkz/)

Comment: Thanks Fiddle! It really helps, but I didnt use redraw(). I can edit a node directly once I get it by using get_node().

Comment: Well, if I comment out `redraw` the tree will still get new values in the background but they won't show up on the page.